# How can I change the color property of a hyperlink on mouse over of an image map?

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink, imagemap

I was browsing other user questions a few minutes ago.. and it led me to trying to change the hover color of the hyperlink on mouse over of my image map.

Any idea how I might accomplish this for the 1 hyperlink I have up?

http://www.urlgone.com/d7ccf8/

Comment: yeah.. works for me.  problem?

Comment: Just checking, it took a while to load and I wasn't 100% sure I arrived at the right destination.  All's well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jquery as i can see.
So do something like that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("area[shape='poly']").mouseover(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('a.staffs').removeClass('active'); //make other link not ative
            $('a.staff-' + id).addClass('active');
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('a.staffs').removeClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And CSS (you have to change it to your style):

```
<style>
    .active {
        color:red;
        text-decoration:underline;  
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hmm...  I'm only proficient at php so the obvious part to you is a bit confusing to me.  The world of jquery is foreign to me.  The map script is a 3rd party script so I simply inserted it.  I do appreciate the answer though.  If jquery is the only solution, I may have to venture down that road soon.

Comment: Step by step tutorial:
1). You have to add `class="staffs"` to each link, e.g. `<a class="staffs" href="http://allhomes.ws/alabama/">Alabama</a>`. I hope you generate it in php (loop).
2). You also have to add an unique class to each of it. For example, for Alabama it will be `staff-A50`. (`<a class="staffs staff-A50" href="http://allhomes.ws/alabama/">Alabama</a>`) For Colorado `staff-A31` etc.
3). Now just paste the code from my answer right before `body` tag.

That's it!

Comment: Try now. Replace srcipt and add css. That's will work, i've checked it on your site. And one more: you insert the code twice. There's no need to do it.
And you have a link only for Alabama, so it will be work only with it. When you create link for each state it will automatically works.

Comment: You sir..  are brilliant.  :)  Thanks so much.  You made my day.  I really appreciate the extra mile.  Not many people online are willing to do that.  Many thanks.

Comment: (I guess I can't vote your answer up because it's my first question and I need 15 rep.. but I'll do it later when I build it up.)

Comment: 1 last quick follow-up.  How would I now style the hyperlink to look different in a default state (remove the underline and change the color) before the hover?

Comment: Add this to the style block:

`.staffs {
   color:black;
   text-decoration:none
}`